# Embedded python issue

Tags: python, c++

I am new to Python and embedded python altogether.

When trying to run some basic python commands from C++, It seems that some of my imports do not work from C++ but they do work when I run them from python shell.

This is the basic instructions that I am trying to run.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:/svapp/')
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:/svapp/test')


from common import baseaccess
from debug.domains.pm import pm_tools
```

In my C++ file it looks like this :

```
int main(){

    Py_SetProgramName("myPythonProgram");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys,os");
    PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");

    PyList_Append(sys_path, PyString_FromString("c:\\svapp"));
    PyList_Append(sys_path, PyString_FromString("c:\\svapp\\test"));
    PyObject * commonModule = PyImport_ImportModule("common");
    PyObject * debugDomainsModule = 
    PyImport_ImportModule("debug.domains.pm.pm_tools");

}
```

The common modules seems to load just fine but when i try to load the debug.domains.pm.pm_tools it seems to import some of the inner imports.

The trace of the error ends with :

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\namednodes__init__.py", line 30, in 
>       from . import settings
>   ImportError: cannot import name settings

Could you please point me in the right direction?
why this is happening only through the embedded C++ app?

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: Not sure what pm_tools is but, if it's a symbol instead of a package then it could be due to the different way you import it. In one case you use import, in the other you use "from" which behaves in a similar but different way

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was able to find that the issue was due to some python native import that was expecting argv[''] argument. After adding this argument to the sys.path everything worked like a charm.

Comment: How about writing the answer? Maybe someone could benefit of it.

Comment: apparently, as mentioned in my previous answer this is the part that caused python2.7  namednodes package to misbehave : PyRun_SimpleString("sys.argv = ['']");                                                  
Adding this line to my embedded code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Call [`Py_SetPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath) before `Py_Initialize`
- Set [`Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag) to `1` before `Py_Initialize`

`Py_SetPath` on windows uses a `;` as a path separator. On other platforms it is `:`